# Unable to see my project file in the IntelliJ folder structure

Tags: intellij-idea, installation, project, intellij-14

I installed the IntelliJ IDEA, while installing I got a dialogue box related to folder structure, but I denied to access it.  Now I created a new project JavaApp but it is getting disappeared when I open my IntelliJ

Please help me with a solution.

I tried it today and was expecting the project file in the folder structure in my Intellij

Comment: What do you mean by "project disappeared"?